# Removing line breaks from bibtex file in emacs

Tags: regex, emacs, bibtex

I have a bibtex file (produced by jabref) and I would like to remove the linebreaks in the fields, e.g.,

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Sims1994b,
  author =       {Sims, K.},
  title =        {{Evolving 3D Morphology and Behavior by
                 Competition.}},
  booktitle =    {{Proceedings of the 4th International Conference on
                 Artificial Life}},
  pages =        {28--39},
  year =         1994
}
```

should become

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Sims1994b,
  author =       {Sims, K.},
  title =        {{Evolving 3D Morphology and Behavior by Competition.}},
  booktitle =    {{Proceedings of the 4th International Conference on Artificial Life}},
  pages =        {28--39},
  year =         1994
}
```

unfortunately my regexp-fu is not up to the task :-)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I played with various variations on `"{{\\(.*^J\\).*}}"` but I cannot capture the text between one or two pairs of curly braces and remove newlines only there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example you gave, this does the job:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\({[^=},]+\)^J +` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\1` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I couldn't figure out how to force the SO formatter to include it, but the `\1` should be followed by a *space*, as "Competition" and "Artificial" will be glued to "by" and "on" if you omit it.

Also note that `^J` represents a *quoted insertion* of a newline (but from your comment above I assume you already know that that's produced by issuing <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>).

---

The `\1` in the replacement text is a *back reference* to the first parenthesized group. This tells Emacs to include the content that matches the portion of the regexp between the `\(` and `\)` in the replacement string (and discard/overwrite everything else).

---

In case you're not already familiar with it, [re-builder](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/04/12/re-builder-interactive-regexp-builder/) is an excellent (built-in!) tool for building up regexps incrementally.

Comment: Thanks, the inner `[^=},]` got me there!